# How to convert different strings in python list to array in bash script

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I'm having a python program in `printlist.py`file. I want to take the result of the `printlist.py` to array in bash script.

Here is python list output:

```
['Google USA (US Dollars, million)','Google UK (sf.nk)','Google India(rk,lp)']
```

I executed this command to assign the list to empty array `arr`:

```
mapfile -t arr < <(python3 /path/printlist.py | sed 's/[][]//g;s/, /\n/g')
```

When I print each string in the array I'm not getting a complete string.

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
done
```

Eg: `Google USA (US Dollars` instead of `Google USA (US Dollars, million)`

**How to convert the python list to an array so that it can print all variables perfectly. Thank You.**

Comment: Write a python script to convert your script output to a newline separated list. Then use mapfile. But anyway, consider using a common data format from your `printlist.py` pyhon program in the first place, like JSON, or output newline or zero separated list from it.

Comment: @KamilCuk. I did that but got the same output as earlier.

Comment: `I did that` Well, what does "that" refer to exactly? Did you wrote a separate python script to convert your script output to a newline separated script? Did you modify `printlist.py` to output data in JSON format or as a newline separated list? What format is used by `printlist.py` script to output the data?

Comment: @KamilCuk I add a loop to print each string to new line but still it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your python script, print your list like this, with null delimiters:

```
for i in mylist:
    print(i, end = "\000")
```

Then in bash, copy the output to an array like this:

```
mapfile -td '' myarr < <(python3 /path/printlist.py)
```

Comment: It's printing very good but when I'm passing again to the **.env** file it's printing** 'Google USA (US Dollars,' 'million)'** can you please add a little code so that even when we pass it to the **.env** file it should look **"Google USA (US Dollars, million)"**

Comment: @swarna You can add double quotes by changing the print function in python to `print('"' + i + '"' + "\000", end = "")`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please try to print the newline separated list as
KamilCuk comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

l = ['Google USA (US Dollars, million)','Google UK (sf.nk)','Google India(rk,lp)']
for i in l:
    print(i)
```

Then feed the output to `mapfile`.
If you still have some specific reason that you need to separate it in `bash`, please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

line="['Google USA (US Dollars, million)','Google UK (sf.nk)','Google India(rk,lp)']"
# equivalent to line=$(python3 /path/printlist.py)

line=${line#[}                  # remove leading left square bracket
line=${line%]}                  # remove trailing right square bracket

pat="'([^']*)(.+)"
while :; do
    if [[ $line =~ $pat ]]; then
        if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} != "," ]]; then
            arr+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
        fi
        line=${BASH_REMATCH[2]} # update "line" to the remaining substring
    else
        break                   # no more matches
    fi
done

# see the result
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
   echo "$i"
done
```

Output:

```
Google USA (US Dollars, million)
Google UK (sf.nk)
Google India(rk,lp)
```

- The pattern `([^']*)(.+)` matches 0 or more string of non-singlequote
  characters (captured as group1) followed by any characters (captured as group2).
- Then the group1 captures substring surrounded by the single quotes *or* a comma separating the list.
- the variable `line` is assigned to the remaining substring and the loop
  repeats till the end of the string.

I need to say the bash script above is **not** complete because it does not consider the case the string contains the single quote.

Answer (score 1):

This processes the python output to make it valid CSV.
Requires bash v5.1+ for the loadable `csv` command.

```sh
# line=$(python printlist.py)
line="['Google USA (US Dollars, million)','Google UK (sf.nk)','Google India(rk,lp)']"

csv_string=${line#\[}                   # remove leading bracket
csv_string=${csv_string%\]}             # remove trailing bracket
csv_string=${csv_string//\"/\"\"}       # double any double quotes
csv_string=${csv_string//\'/\"}         # convert single to double quotes

BASH_LOADABLES_PATH=${BASH/bin/lib}
enable -f csv csv

csv -a elements "$csv_string"
declare -p elements
```

outputs

```
declare -a elements=([0]="Google USA (US Dollars, million)" [1]="Google UK (sf.nk)" [2]="Google India(rk,lp)")
```